# Web Push Php Library Example - Strict Origin When Cross Origin

Tags: php, web-push, referrer-policy

I used Web Push PHP library
https://github.com/Minishlink/web-push-php-example to send push notifications, but I found a problem:

> Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

For your information, I used

1. PHP --Version

> ```
> PHP 7.2.34 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Nov  4 2020 16:02:13)
> Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
> ```

2. Link to this sample: https://i-confident.com/admin/web-push-php-example/src/index.html

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Your issue is a apache or nginx issue, not a php one, search for cors setting for your http server

Answer (score 0):

use

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); or both
header('Content-type: application/json'); (if want to access your json post data )

**in your send_push_notification.php file at the top**
and also use "www." for your url "https://i-confident.com/.." cause i recently face issue in which i didnt add www. in my url and was not receiving post/get data in my targeted file.
```

Comment: bro  can you send me the network view snap where your api hit response is showing ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need install php extension in my case:

```
sudo apt install php7.4-gmp
```

Also you need the checkout the branch:

```
git checkout v2.x
```

Then you should update your dependencies via composer:

```
composer update
```

And then it's should work I checked.

[image]

Comment: I use centos not ubuntu
sudo: apt: command not found

Comment: @Nere `yum install php-gmp`, maybe something like this

Comment: See here - https://serverfault.com/questions/855344/how-to-install-enable-gmp-math-functions-for-php-on-centos